# updates to fuse.conf are not available

Tags: fuse

I'm attempting to add the following so that I can use my Nexus 4 with Ubuntu. But the change in `/etc/fuse.conf` doesn't seem to be captured by the system. See below.

```
system76:~$ sudo tail -1 /etc/fuse.conf; id -a; android-connect

user_allow_other

104(fuse)

fusermount: failed to open /etc/fuse.conf: Permission denied
fusermount: option allow_other only allowed if 'user_allow_other' is set in /etc/fuse.conf
```

What am I missing?

Comment: shall we see the complete /etc/fuse.conf ?

Comment: # Set the maximum number of FUSE mounts allowed to non-root users.
# The default is 1000.
#
#mount_max = 1000

# Allow non-root users to specify the 'allow_other' or 'allow_root'
# mount options.
#
user_allow_other

Comment: sorry for the late  I went offline.

Answer (score 1):

edit your `/etc/fuse.conf` with following modifications.

```
# Set the maximum number of FUSE mounts allowed to non-root users.
# The default is 1000.

mount_max = 1000

# Allow non-root users to specify the 'allow_other' or 'allow_root'
# mount options.

user_allow_other
```

I mean Just remove the Hash(#).

Answer (score 1):

To pickup conf file, you have to add your user to "fuse" group.

```
sudo addgroup <username> fuse,
```

You also have to relogin

```
sudo pkill -u username
```